# O* in complexity

Tags: time-complexity, complexity-theory

What is the definition O* in time complexity? Do you know the literature in which this notion defined? I saw it in parameterized complexity papers and couldn't find the formal definition.

Example: O*(n)?

Comment: Did the paper explain the notation? what paper?

Comment: @DavidBuck nothing in the footnotes.

Comment: O(n) means a operation takes time proportional to the number of items operated on. O(n squared ) means it takes time  proportional to the square of the number. Who's this O guy? Not me, that's for sure. It means "on the **o**rder of.

Comment: @PatrickArtner For example here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.04185.pdf

Comment: @O.Jones check this paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1808.04185.pdf

Comment: There is an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672281/what-is-the-difference-between-the-big-o-and-big-o-star-asterisk-operator) which has further links.

Comment: @DavidBuck Do you know any literature in which this notion defined?

Comment: It's right there in a comment on the linked question which links to [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X0700128X)